# Handle concurrent request in MS SQL for selecting data from a table randomly and updating the column of that particular row as used

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, web-services

We have one rest service which can be called by concurrent users and scenario where it is failing is when 2 parallel users are fetching same data from the table before user 1 update the flag

Say Table is 'SeedData' having columns 'id','SeedVaule','SeedUsedFlag' and requirement is to select 'SeedValue' randomly from this table and update the 'SeedUsedFlag' as TRUE

Service is using hibernate for ORM with SQL Server version 2012

Options which i googled are

1. Changing the isolation level in SQL Server
2. Using stored procedure to select and update

but i am not clear which one to opt for or any better way is available because we are dealing with million of record in SeedData table and performance is major consideration.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to do an SELECT and then UPDATE (to pessimistically lock the rows at the same time)

I do not think an ORM is able to handle this well...especially in high concurrency situations.

The below will do a select inside the CTE, and then an update on those rows.

The "hints" ( UPDLOCK, READPAST , ROWLOCK ) will help with concurrency.
You can research them, but basically, if any row is currently locked (by another transaction), the READPAST will skip over them.  You can research the other hints.

Also note the "ORDER BY NEWID()" trick below.

HOWEVER, I would AVOID any order-by statement...to help with performance.  Remember, if you have 1 million rows...and you want to update 10 of them...the moment you put in an "order-by", you have to order all 1 million to find the correct 10.  leaving off the order-by will avoid that and help performance tremendously.

```
declare @TopSize int = 10

WITH cte1 AS       
 (  SELECT 
      TOP (@TopSize) 

   TelevisionUUID , –<<Note, the columns here must be available to the output
   IsCheckedOut        
      FROM   
            dbo.Television tv      
    WITH ( UPDLOCK, READPAST , ROWLOCK ) –<<Optional Hints, but helps with concurrency issues   
      WHERE  
            IsCheckedOut = 0              
      ORDER BY
            /* tv.TelevisionKey DESC */
            NEWID() /* this will give you randomness */
)
UPDATE cte1
      SET  IsCheckedOut = 1
;
```

Here is the full (generic) example I wrote:

```
———-START TSQL

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Television]’) and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N’IsUserTable’) = 1)
      BEGIN
            DROP TABLE [dbo].[Television]
      END
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Television] (
      TelevisionUUID [uniqueidentifier] not null default NEWSEQUENTIALID() ,
      TelevisionName varchar(64) not null ,
      TelevisionKey int not null ,
      IsCheckedOut bit default 0
)    
GO


ALTER TABLE dbo.Television ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Television_TelevisionUUID
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TelevisionUUID)
GO


ALTER TABLE dbo.Television ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Television_TelevisionName_UNIQUE
UNIQUE (TelevisionName)
GO


set nocount on

declare @counter int
select @counter = 11000
declare @currentTVName varchar(24)
declare @TopSize int
select @TopSize = 10

while @counter > 10000  — this loop counter is ONLY here for fake data,….do not use this syntax for production code
begin

      select @currentTVName = ‘TV:     ‘+ convert(varchar(24) , @counter)

      INSERT into dbo.Television ( TelevisionName , TelevisionKey ) values ( @currentTVName , @counter)

      select @counter = @counter – 1     
end


select count(*) as TV_Total_COUNT from dbo.Television

/*
–Does not Work!
Update TOP (10) dbo.Television
      Set IsCheckedOut = 1
FROM
      dbo.Television tv
ORDER BY tv.TelevisionKey
*/
declare @AuditTrail table ( TelevisionUUID uniqueidentifier , OldIsCheckedOut bit , NewIsCheckedOut bit )

;
WITH cte1 AS       
 (  SELECT 
      TOP (@TopSize) 

   TelevisionUUID , –<<Note, the columns here must be available to the output
   IsCheckedOut        
      FROM   
            dbo.Television tv      
    WITH ( UPDLOCK, READPAST , ROWLOCK ) –<<Optional Hints, but helps with concurrency issues   
      WHERE  
            IsCheckedOut = 0              
      ORDER BY
            tv.TelevisionKey DESC        
)
UPDATE cte1
      SET  IsCheckedOut = 1
output inserted.TelevisionUUID , deleted.IsCheckedOut , inserted.IsCheckedOut into @AuditTrail ( TelevisionUUID , OldIsCheckedOut , NewIsCheckedOut )
;
print ”
print ‘Newly Checked Out Items’
select * from dbo.Television tv where tv.IsCheckedOut <> 0

print ‘Output AuditTrail’
select * from @AuditTrail
print ‘Not checked out items’
select count(*) as TVCOUNTIsNOTCheckedOut from dbo.Television tv where tv.IsCheckedOut = 0
```

If you only need to pessimistically lock a single row...the code above can be reworked......to avoid the select top X CTE......but using the same principals.